# Zoom in on a specific area (<area>) on a floor plan (<map></map>)

Tags: jquery, html, imagemapster

Is there a way to zoom in on a specific  on a  using jQuery? I am creating an interactive floorplan on which when you click on a certain  it will zoom in on that specific coordinate using HTML5, ImageMapster jQuery and jQuery.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided minimal HTML/Javascript to demonstrate, as well as what you've tried so far. See [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q076ksyL/

what is does is that there is a search bar, once it locates the area (by ID) it will zoom in on that area with a highlight(which is done by the image.mapster).